# What C++ container should I choose for frequency graph?

Tags: c++, containers, frequency

I have a little project. I want to make a frequency graph something like this:

```
a-axis
3|    x
2|`   x        x
1|    x  x     x
0| x  x  x     x
 |`_____________`
   2  4  6  7  9  b-axis
```

What container should I use and how do go about implementing that in the simplest way.

- The container should also record zero value (frequency).

I find it difficult to correct implement the container. Is there are any sample code I can look at? Or anybody can write a sample for me to study here.

Update:
I was thinking of making `std::map<int,std::vector<int>> keyAndMap`
How do I access the vector which is inside keyAndMap?
Because I somehow can't do `keyAndMap.insert(std::make_pair<int,std::vector<int>>(bAxis,bVec.push_back(bValue)));`
The main problem I think is how to generate unique vector for each key in std::map?

```
const int tries = 21;
std::vector<int>values;
std::map<int,std::vector<int>>keyAndMap;
for (int i = 1; i < tries; i++)
{
    int n = i;
    int cycle = calculate(n);
    /*This next line is an error... why?*/
    keyAndMap.insert(std::make_pair<int,std::vector<int>>(cycle,values.push_back(i)));
}
```

although if i somehow got through that line, my logic here is flawed because the vector is not unique to each key. 
Each 'x' in the little pretty graph i drew is gained with each pass in the loop.
So for each b-axis (2,4,6,7, and 9) should be in their own std::vector

Comment: By container you preferably mean data structure?

Comment: Sounds like you want a `std::map<int, int>`

Comment: Asking for code is generally frowned upon. Also I find it a bit unclear what exactly the problem is or what the criteria are? What's wrong with a simple `std::vector`? Or maybe a `std::map`?

Comment: You only showed us a picture.  You didn't give information on what the actual data items it is you need to keep / record.

Comment: What are the possible ranges for a and b?

Comment: When in doubt, choose `std::vector`. Only when you have a real reason why that won't work, look for alternatives.  Good rule of thumb.

Comment: As @NathanOlivier mentioned - use `std::map<int, int>` where first template (key) will be representing X-Axis, since both keys and values of X-Axis must be unique, and the second one will be representing value of that key, meaning: position in Y-Axis. EDIT: To you update: if you have, for example `std::vector<std::vector>> a(5, std::vector<int>(5));` you can access it simply by using `operator[]`. So a[0][0] will be top left record of your 'matrix'

Comment: `vector<int>` is enough

Answer (score 2):

> What container should I use and how do go about implementing that in the simplest way?

A possible container would be a `std::map<key, frequency>`, both of which are of type `int`, with the additional advantage of your values being sorted. Then you could simply read values by something like:

```
std::map<int, int> data;

int key;
while (std::cin >> key)
{
    ++data[key]; // increment the frequency of a given key*
}
```

> To access the `data` you could use iterators, like so:

```
for (auto it = data.begin; it != data.end(); ++it)
{
    // iterator to key  
    std::cout << it->first <<": "<< it->second <<"\n";
                              // iterator to frequency
}
```

Which will print a two-column table of your data.

### Second, even simpler approach:

You could use a `std::vector<frequency>`, where `frequency` is of type `int`, and your data would be the indexes of the `std::vector`, **however**, you should know the *range*** of your data so that you can use it as an initial vector size:
i.e. `std::vector<int> data(5, 0)` could hold values with *range* `5`.

Then if, for example, your data is consisted of the integers: [0, 4], you could have:

```
std::vector<int> data(5, 0); // five elements with initial value 0

int key;
while(std::cin >> key)  // assuming key >= 0 && key < 5
{
    data[key] += 1;  
}
```

and then print with:

```
for (int i= 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << i <<": "<< data[i] <<"\n";
}
```

---

<sup>* The default initial `frequency` value of a distinct `key` is: `0`, so you can simply use the key to access and increment an element.</sup>

<sup>**range - difference between the lowest and highest values.</sup>